# С помощью css перекрасить png в белый

Tags: css, css-filters

Есть логотипы в png и все они разных цветов. Возможно ли с помощью css их делать белыми? (как в ФШ наложение overlay) 
Или может быть есть какие-то приёмы вёрстки?

Answer (score 1):

Пробуйте поиграть с `filter: invert` и `filter: grayscale`. А вообще, учитывая, что люди все чаще просматривают сайты на ретина-дисплеях, логотипы лучше делать в svg, с этим форматом гораздо проще работать в css. А еще лучше - переводить логотипы вместе с иконками в иконочный шрифт, тогда с цветом и прочими параметрами вообще проблем не будет.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body{
background: mediumpurple
}

img {
  width: 300px;
}

.white {
  filter: grayscale(1) brightness(1000%);
}

.black {
  filter: brightness(0);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a">
<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a" class="white">
<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a" class="black">
```

Comment: Ответ Artem Gorlachev является лукавством, так как черный цвет в предлагаемом логотипе на самом деле не черный, а #212325, настоящий черный и почти черный данный способ в белый не перекрасит

Answer (score 0):

Например, можно добавить overlay с помощью `:after`:

```css
.img-container {
  position: relative;
}

.img-container:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" />
</div>
```